# WPF C# Read access table and modify UI dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, database, tracking, dynamic-ui

I am newbie in WPF. I am doing an application to tracking the subway position in line. So, my UI has a lot of rectangles that represents regions of train line. I have an access table that tell me dynamically me if each region is occupied or not (The table has 2 columns, the 'Name' of region and its 'Status' - If 'Status' is true the region is occupied, if 'Status' is false is not). So a need to read from this table and if the region is  occupied I have to color the corresponding region(the rectangle) of red.  Any suggestion to give a quick start?  I am using VS 2013 and WPF C#.net. Thanks a lot!